# How to pass model params when 2 models to same route

Tags: ember.js

I am having trouble with getting the params of the user with multiple models to a route. At first I had this code:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('user', params.id);
    }
});
```

That worked fine and passed all user params.

However now I need data from the 'game' model. This code below successfully gets the 'game' data to the template but now I have no user params and I keep getting syntax errors when trying to put the code in to pass them.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      game: store.find('game'),
      user: store.find('user')
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, models) {
    var game = models.game;
    var user = models.user;

    controller.set('content', game);
    controller.set('user', user);
  }
});
```

I was wondering how I can have 2 models going to 1 route and the params for user also.

I also don't fully understand `setupController` and what I need to put in my index controller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you do a *store.find()* without specifying which object to find, it will return all objects of that type. So you'll have an array.

If you want to find a *user* with a specific id (from params maybe), you'd do:

```
this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
```

Notice the *this.* before *store*.

As for the game, I'd need to see how your *user* and *game* models are set up, and the relationships between them. But basically, unless you're using nested routes, you'd have to have a way to find one or all games based on the user, once you have gotten the user in your model.

I would remove the *setup_controller* completely, as there is no need for it here. You can access *user* and/or *game* in your template like so:

```
model.user
model.game
```

Or you can add two computed properties on the controller:

```
user: function(){
    return this.get('model.user');
}.property('model.user'),

game: function() {
    return this.get('model.game');
}.property('model.game')
```

And in your template, you'd access them simply as *user* or *game*.